# Weird property of the functions $f(x)=x^e, g(x)=x^\pi$ and $h(x)=x^\sqrt{2}$

Tags: functions

I was messing around on desmos and all of these functions seem to be only defined for $x=0$ and $x>0$. Is this an error on desmos' part or are they really only defined for $x=0$ and $x>0$ and if so, why? Does it have something to do with the exponents being irrational and what about the exponents being irrational makes these functions undefined for negative values?

Comment: Desmos is likely ignoring the case for $x<0$ because [these functions are complex-valued](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%7BRe%5Bx%5EPi%5D%2CIm%5Bx%5EPi%5D%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D) in this domain.

Comment: Do you happen to know why they are imaginary in this domain?

Comment: @finnbratfisch You can use the fact that $e^{i\pi} = -1$ as a starting point.

Comment: @finnbratfisch Well, with a little hand waving we could write $x^\pi=(\sqrt x)^{2\pi}$.  What do we know about the square roots of negative real numbers?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, but could you tell me why $x^\pi=(\sqrt{x})^{2\pi}$?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson And moreover multivalued , so we would have to choose a specific branch. Therefore, it makes sense to declare $a^b$ undefined for $a<0$ and irrational $b$.

Comment: @Peter It is multivalued but I thought this was TMI and would confuse the OP.

Comment: @finnbratfisch This is a rule of exponents (although I am ignoring some technicalities such as multivaluedness). Simply write $x^\pi=x^{2\pi/2}=(x^{1/2})^{2\pi}=(\sqrt x)^{2\pi}$.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson This exponention rule is not correct if $x$ is not a nonnegative real number. This incorrectness is used in many fake-proofs, so it is no good idea to write $x^{\pi}$ this way , if $x$ is negative.

Comment: @Peter Yes Peter. I know. But the OP does not have sufficient background for the correct explanation you gave. What I wrote gives a heuristic approach to understanding why it's complex valued at an appropriate level for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $x^y = e^{y \ln x}$.  This raises the question of how to take the logarithm of a negative number.  It can be done by using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.  So, if you can express a complex number in polar form as $x = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) = re^{i\theta}$, then $\ln x = \ln r + i\theta$.

If $x$ is a negative real number, then we must have $\cos \theta = -1$ and $\sin \theta = 0$, which means that $\theta$ must be an *odd* multiple of $\pi$, i.e., $\theta = (2n + 1)\pi$ for some integer $n$.  So $\ln x = \ln r + i(2n + 1)\pi$.

So, for the case of $f(x) = x^e$ (with $x$ negative), that works out to $f(x) = e^{e(\ln r + i(2n + 1)\pi)} = e^{e \ln r}e^{ie(2n + 1)\pi} = r^e(\cos (e(2n + 1)\pi) + i \sin (e(2n + 1)\pi))$.  This is a real number only if $e(2n + 1)$ is an integer.  But because $e$ is an irrational number, that never happens.  Therefore, the function must be complex-valued.

Comment: I wish I could understand this because it is most likely right but I don't.